# escape special chars after reading from mysql for output in php

Tags: php, sql-server, escaping

I am trying to output the results from a field that is read from mysql.
the field has this in it.

```
< ? echo "yes"; ? >
```

however when i try to print the field... it is null.

do i have to escape it on output?

i dont want to execute the code.. i want to output what is in the field as text

Comment: Include the actual code sample. The error is not in your data, it's in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape with [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

```
$val = htmlspecialchars ('<?php echo "yes"; ?>');
echo $val;
```

Comment: i dont want to execute the code.. i want to output what is in the field as text.

Comment: i dont think you understand the question.. please read it again

Comment: Now I figured out, check answer

Comment: At least now I understand the question. ^^

Answer (score 1):

I guess htmlspecialchars is that what you want:

```
<?php
$str = "<?php echo 'lol'; ?>";
echo htmlspecialchars($str);
?>
```

it outputs `<?php echo 'lol'; ?>`